# Need to display costs with 1/10 cent values in superscript

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with prices similar to those of gasoline at the pump. I have prices that look like $3.799.

I can `rounddown(A1,2)` to get 3.79 and `1000*(Round(A1,3)-Roundown(A1,2))` will get the 9 but I can't find a way to concat them so that everything after the “&” symbol is in superscript.

```
rounddown(A1,2)&       int(1000*(Round(A1,3)-Roundown(A1,2)))
^ This regular         ^ This in Superscript
```

Best I have so far is to take the `int(1000*(Round(A1,3)-Roundown(A1,2)))` into a lookup table to get the Unichar character because they aren't sequential. It would be MUCH easier if there was a number format for working in 1/10 cent prices.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a string (or cell) that consists of "0⁰1¹2²  ...  9⁹" and then work with [`LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `LEN`, and especially `FIND`](https://datatofish.com/excel-string-functions-left-right-mid-len-find/) to pick out the superscript you want?  Repeat for 10ths and 100ths?  Perhaps it needs to be encapsulated in a user-defined function (and if you do that there might even be easier ways).

Comment: Does [Superscript part of a cell containing a formula \[SOLVED\]](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1002865-superscript-part-of-a-cell-containing-a-formula.html) answer your question?

Comment: Does [Superscript part value in a cell using Excel and VBA | Exceldome](https://www.exceldome.com/solutions/superscript-part-value-in-a-cell/) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can only differentially format the characters in an Excel cell is there is an actual text string in that cell (not a text string that is the result of a formula).

This generally means using VBA to create the text string, either by copying the value from some other cell, or doing the calculation within VBA.

In the example below, I write the result with the superscripted number to the right of the actual value, but you can adapt the code in many ways.

To make it dynamic, I use a worksheet_change code so that whenever you change something in column A, it will superscript the result in column B

You will need to adapt the code to your actual use.

To enter this event-triggered Macro, right click on the sheet tab.
Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
Then paste the code below into the window that opens.

Be sure to set `dataRange` to the range where you want this to occur.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
Set dataRange = Columns(1)

If Not Intersect(Target, dataRange) Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In Intersect(Target, dataRange)
        With c.Offset(0, 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = Format(c, "0.000")
            .Characters(Len(.Value), 1).Font.Superscript = True
        End With
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

*In the code above, because of the `Format` function, values will be Rounded to three decimal digits. If this is undesired, you could include a function to truncate rather than round, before applying the Format function*

[image]

Since there are unicode characters for all of the superscripted numbers, you can also use a formula in a "helper" column:

```
=LET(x, TEXT(A1,"0.000"),
     y, LEFT(x,LEN(x)-1),
     z, UNICHAR(INDEX({8304;185;178;179;8308;8309;8310;8311;8312;8313}, RIGHT(x)+1)),
     y&z)
```

I used the `Let` function available in 365 for readability, but this could be re-written to allow use in earlier versions if necessary.